# How to draw a circle with a linear gradient

Tags: blackberry, user-interface

Does anyone know how can I draw such a thing in BlackBerry? This SVG sample should help you understand what am I trying to achieve. Paste it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_linear) to see the result in your browser.

```
<html>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#0069A9;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#014C79;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="200" rx="85" ry="85" fill="url(#grad1)" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

`Graphics.drawShadedFilledPath` function won't let me draw a perfect circle and unfortunatelly I can't use the SVG sample above either.

Comment: Not an actual answer to your question, but it would probably be easier to just have a higher resolution copy of your image and then scale it down in the app.

Comment: or drop the gradient altogether. I'm considering all possible options.

Comment: Bit of long shot but another idea is to draw a square gradient first using Graphics.drawShadedFilledPath, then create a circular mask using Graphics.drawEllipsis. Not even sure if this is possible but thought I'd post it up as I couldn't figure out any other way of even potentially doing this.